# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Powershell install 'SQLSERVERAGENT' error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to locally install SQL Server 2012 via Powershell and keep running into the error:

```
The following error occurred:
The credentials you provided for the 'SQLSERVERAGENT' service is invalid.
Error result: -2068578304
Result facility code: 1204
Result error code: 0
```

The following is the simple line for executing the install.

```
&'D:\FilePath\setup.exe' /QS /ConfigurationFile=C:\FilePath\ConfigurationFile.ini
```

In the ConfigurationFile.ini the following:

```
SQLSVCACCOUNT="HT\SqlSrvBK"
SQLSVCPASSWORD="P@ssWord!@#$"
```

Granted there's more to the ConfigurationFile.ini but they are the main lines related the the issue I believe.

I have also tried to pass the password in directly such as:

```
&'D:\FilePath\setup.exe' /QS /ConfigurationFile=C:\FilePath\ConfigurationFile.ini /SQLSVCPASSWORD="P@ssWord!@#$"
```

Also tried is getting it from the Powershell as a string or a secure string and escaping any symbols that would get fileted out such as "$". I'm positive the password is correct as running the process via the GUI works 100% of the time. My environment is on Windows server 2012, being ran with VMware. I have tried local admin accounts as well as domain admin accounts. Thank you for any advice and/or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing `AGTSVCACCOUNT` and `AGTSVCPASSWORD` variables?  Your example only specifies the credentials for the database engine service, not the agent service.

Comment: They are included in the ConfigurationFile.ini, I will admit I am new to powershell and that must show with that over site in the question. I'm going to rerun the process passing the password directly into the powershell command and remove the AGTSVCPASSWORD from the ConfigurationFile.ini and retuen with any results. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thank you, my problem seemed to be that I had the AGTSVCPASSWORD in my ConfigurationFile.ini and had the same format as everything else. (AGTSVCPASSWORD="P@ssWord!@#$") and I'm guessing the password contained a symbol that was not escaping somewhere. Using /AGTSVCPASSWORD='P@ssWord!@#$' with single brackets in the powershell command window worked vs the double in the .ini file. Thanks again!